# How to import from a webpack bundle using my own node backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, bundle

Given the 'webpack' bundle '/external_modules/seeso/dist/seeso.js' from the 'seeso' package and a node backend I wrote that sends files according to their path:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import express from 'express'
const app = express();
const PORT = 20000;

app.use('/public', express.static('public'))
app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'))
app.use('/my_modules', express.static('my_modules'))
app.use('/external_modules', express.static('external_modules'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/public/index.html');
    //res.sendFile(new URL('./index.html', import.meta.url).pathname)
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

How should I change my code to allow imports like the below to work?

```
import Seeso, {InitializationErrorType, CalibrationAccuracyCriteria} from '/external_modules/seeso/dist/seeso.js';
```

This is the error I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/external_modules/seeso/dist/seeso.js' does not provide an export named 'CalibrationAccuracyCriteria' (at easy-seeso.js:2:34)
```